# How to combine rows hours into just one day with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Are you able to use MongoDB to combine rows of data into one row?

I'm using dates with year, month, day and hour.  The data is shown per hour.  Is there a way to combine data of the hours into just one day with data. I would basically remove the hour column and sum the hour data into per day data.

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to understand exactly what you mean. Can you provide some code, that will make this question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the data is shown per hour" - do you mean it's stored in the database that way?

MongoDB doesn't have rows and columns - the equivalent of a row is a document, and the column equivalent is a field. Unlike in traditional SQL, a field isn't just one piece of information (a string, number/date, boolean, null, etc). It can be more than one piece of data - it can be an array, or a document, or an array of documents, etc.

Anyway, based on the small amount of information I have on your situation, I'd absolutely design the data with the bucket pattern. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern

You could $unset the 'measurements' array and just keep the sum/count fields if that's what you want.

If your data is already set in stone, then I'd use an aggregation pipeline to group all the documents ('rows') together - the group _id would be year, month, day, and you could sum/count/min/max/etc the data in the group too.